# @Loader with @NamedNativeQuery NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entity classes:

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String title;

    private String code;
    private long price;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Loader(namedQuery = "productFields")
    private List<ProductOwnerFields> fields = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ProductPhoto> photos = new HashSet<>();

    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
@NamedNativeQueries({@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "productFields",
        resultClass = ProductOwnerFields.class,
        query = "select p.* " +
                "from productownerfields p " +
                "   left outer join templatefields t " +
                "       on p.templateField_id = t.id " +
                "where p.product_id = ? " +
                "order by t.order_field desc"
)})
public class ProductOwnerFields {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    private String customValue;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "templateField_id")
    private TemplateFields templateFields;

    //getters and setters
}
```

and DAO:

```
@Repository
public class IProductDao implements ProductDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Product find(int id) {
        return entityManager.find(Product.class, id);
    }
}
```

When I try to get product by find method I get exception for field calls "fields" of Product class:
*unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception.*

In a trace is named query is run:

> **TRACE** o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as
>   [INTEGER] - [88] **DEBUG** org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 0 **TRACE** o.h.t.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor - extracted value ([id] :
>   [INTEGER]) - [361]  **DEBUG** org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row:
>   EntityKey[com.inetshop.core.entities.ProductOwnerFields#361]

How can I fix this wrong? Set of ProductPhoto load is ok.

Thank for your help!

Comment: can you try left join fetch instead?

Comment: the hibernate makes like request, i mean with left outer join